# How to change the path a KDE task manager icon refers to?

Tags: kde, customization, plasma-5

When I pin a certain application (CLion) to the task manager, and click on the icon, the application fails to start because the icon refers to an incorrect path.

How do I edit that path, such that clicking on the icon starts the application?

I have looked into **plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc**, but cannot find the path in there. With gnome that information is under **/home/fanta/.local/share/applications**, but KDE seems to ignore that directory.

Also note that unpinning the application, and then pinning it again, doesn't help.

I am using KDE Plasma V 5.12.7, KDE Frameworks V 5.44.0, Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: it's ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197347/kde-panel-launcher-files-location

Answer (score 0):

In my case (telegram application) this was found in 
`.local/share/applications/telegramdesktop.desktop`

I didn't find any solution so I had to manually search previous path trails on the home folder and i did just that 
`cd ~/ && grep -iRl "Desktop/Telegram" ./`